# gnuplot: prevent zoom on one axis

Tags: gnuplot

It is possible to prevent zooming on one axis?
I think, in older version just `set yrange [-1.1:1.1:]` really fixed the range, while
`pl [][-1.1:1.1]`  only initialised the range.

But now, zooming with the mouse does not respect the range anymore.

Comment: Which versions of gnuplot are you talking about? I quickly checked 4.6.0 and there is no fixed range when zooming with the mouse. I guess zooming with the mouse always(?) changes both, x and y-range, or have I misunderstood something? What do you mean with zooming? Opening and dragging a rectangle on the graph, e.g. on a wxt or qt terminal, correct?

Comment: Yeah, maybe it was ~4.6. I cannot remember by hard. Have you tried setting the range via `pl []`; maybe that fixed the range. Maybe it was only for rectangle zoom; I think scroll zoom was available later.

Comment: Ok, it is the other way round as you describe in your question. E.g. in gnuplot4.6.0 `plot [][-1:1] sin(x)` will keep the y-range fixed when zooming with the mouse. Apparently, this already changed with gnuplot 4.6.5. Hmmm, currently I have no idea how get this behaviour back in newer versions.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you are using either wxt or qt terminal.
The following is a workaround which in principle does what you are asking for.

Apparently, gnuplot 4.6.0 was keeping a fixed yrange with `plot [][-1.1:1.1] sin(x)` when zooming with the mouse. However, this behaviour changed for gnuplot>4.6.0.

For newer versions you could use a `while` loop with `pause mouse` to mimic this behaviour.

In the example below

- two left mouse button clicks (`MOUSE_KEY=1`) will define the zoom-in x-range and
- a right mouse click (`MOUSE_KEY=3`) will reset the x-range to the original range.
- pressing `ESC` will stop the loop.

**Script:** (works for gnuplot>=5.0.0)

```
### keep fixed y-range when mouse zooming
reset session

ymin = -1.1
ymax =  1.1
set yrange[ymin:ymax]

plot sin(x)

x00 = GPVAL_X_MIN
x11 = GPVAL_X_MAX
x1 = y1 = NaN
continue = 1
while (continue) {
    pause mouse keypress,button3,button1
    x0=x1;   x1=MOUSE_X
    y0=y1;   y1=MOUSE_Y
    mk = MOUSE_KEY
    if (mk==27) { continue=0 }   # press ESC to end loop
    if (mk==3)  { 
        set xrange[x00:x11]      # scale to original range
        x1=y1=NaN
    }
    if (mk==1 && x0==x0 && y0==y0) {
        xr0 = x11>x00 && x1>x0 ? x0 : x1
        xr1 = x11>x00 && x1>x0 ? x1 : x0
        set xrange[xr0:xr1]
        set yrange[ymin:ymax]
        x1=y1=NaN
    }
    replot
}
### end of script
```

**Screen capture:** (from wxt terminal, yellow dot=left click, red dot=right click)

[image]

Comment: Thx, for the efforts. It is a pity that gnuplot lost this good behaviour. BTW, `bind` is also worth to consider. E.g. binding on `Button1` ( `bind "Button1" "set yrange [ymin:ymax]; replot"`), one can keep the zoom-box, at the cost of an additional click.